# Divi favicon insecure link

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Now I applied SSL certificate on my website but there is insecure link in website i can't solve this issue until now , the reason of problem divi favicon link this option not displayed now between options of Divi theme and I couldn't update the URL from database because when I tried to update the link from database the value is automatically changed , do you have any idea how can I change this link ?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240069/favicon-causes-mixed-content-warning-over-ssl possible situation, unfortunetly your question is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this situation not solve my issue cuz favicon link saved on database and when i tried to update it from database some thing in code update my change in database automatically , and in same time divi theme remove favicon textbox from options , so i couldn't update the link from website also

Comment: @EngSabreenSaber remove the current favicon and upload it again. Have you change the SSL URL in Database. To http to https

Comment: from where can I remove it ? i didn't found option in theme to remove it and i could change url from database from http to https

Answer (score 1):

Go the theme.

To add favicon for new Divi version, you need to go to `Theme Customizer -> General Settings -> Site Identity -> Site Icon.`

If the URL is hardcoded as `http` then go to the stylesheet/template system and manually change the `http` to `https` in the theme code.

Otherwise, create a child theme and then make the changes on that, that should prevent the main theme from changing anything back.

TIP: Make sure the base URL of the Theme is `https` as the theme will pull that in by configuring WordPress to use HTTPS through your dashboard. In case you haven’t, you can do so by going to the Settings > General tab. Once you’re in, look for the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) fields:
[image]
If you did that already then force WordPress to use HTTPS by editing the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That should do the trick.

Another thing you can consider is to use a CDN like Cloudflare to load static content (your favicon) over HTTPS

Comment: i tried this but unfortunately old favicon that saved in database still exist and create new favicon , so i still have the issue

Comment: Mmmmm, the favicon in the database should not have any effect on whether it is HTTPS or HTTP.

Is the URL also stored in the DB?

Comment: yes URL stored in database as Http URL in wp_options table

Comment: I updated my answer, I added the htaccess method, which should work.

Comment: Than;s for your reply but that's not solve my issue , I solved it by comment this line echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="'.esc_url( $faviconUrl ).'" />'; in page custom_fuctions

Comment: Interesting, the htacess mod should have fixed that anyway.